# custom cell to always be on top of tableView in segmented controller view

Tags: swift, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol, custom-cell

I have a segmented controller displaying 3 different tableViews, with Case 2 creating a custom cell. I have gotten the custom cell to display in Case 2, but the new cell appears on the bottom of the tableView.

How to I get the custom cell to always appear on the top of the tableView?

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)

    {

    case 0:
        myCell.textLabel!.text = globalList[indexPath.row]
        break

    case 1:
        myCell.textLabel!.text = friendsList[indexPath.row]
        break


    case 2:

    // *** I want to add a Cell here with a "Add Item" IBAction ---------------------

        if(indexPath.row == meList.count) {

            myCell.textLabel?.text = "+ Add Item"
            // add new row here
            /* OR add new button here as cell's subview  */
            // set frame of your button
            // set target and selector method of button
            // [cell addSubView: addButton]

        }
        else {

            myCell.textLabel?.text = meList[indexPath.row]
        }   

    default:
        break

    }

    return myCell

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is check for `indexPath.row == 0` and add the button to that cell. Else, configure the cell as normal, but with the indexPath offset my one.

```
if(indexPath.row == 0) {
    myCell.textLabel?.text = "+ Add Item"
    // add new row here
    /* OR add new button here as cell's subview  */
    // set frame of your button
    // set target and selector method of button
    // [cell addSubView: addButton]

} else {
    myCell.textLabel?.text = meList[indexPath.row - 1]
}
```